# Problems setting up X-Debug in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, xampp, xdebug

I'm trying to get started with X-Debug in Eclipse, but I'm running into a problem that I haven't been able to find an answer to.

X-Debug shows up in the debugger list, but in the PHP Debug menu, I'm not given the option to select it.

I'm using Eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1), and I'm using Apache 2.0 with Xampp. Here is the output of my phpinfo() relating to XDebug. What am I doing wrong?

```
xdebug support  enabled
Version 2.2.5
IDE Key SADQ-PC$
Supported protocols Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol $Revision: 1.145 $
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level    100 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  On  On
xdebug.profiler_enable  On  On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  \   \
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart On  On
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    1   1
xdebug.trace_output_dir \   \
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you can select the debugger by following the link "PHP servers..." going to the "edit" menu for your default server, and going to the debugger tab to select X-Debug from the dropdown menu.